# Why in the Alternating Series Test we need to consider both partial sums with even and odd number of terms?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-explanation

I'm sorry, I think this is a pretty stupid question, but can not we just prove it for 1 of them? I mean, by Definition of Series Convergence :
if partial sum is convergent then the series is convergent. Then won't be proving just for 1 partial sum be enough?

Comment: If you want a proof explained, it's best to give the gist of the proof that you don't understand/want clarified. At the moment, I have no idea which step you have problems with/want to simplify.

Comment: Within the narrow issue of convergence versus divergence, the [alternating series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test) does not distinguish between partial sums with an even versus odd number of terms.  In fact, within this narrow issue,  the alternating series test does not even examine partial sums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If just the odd-numbered partial sums of a series converge, or just the even-numbered, or even if both converge but not to the same limit, that does **not** make the series converge.  For example, consider the series
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + \ldots $$
The odd-numbered partial sums converge, in fact they are all equal to $1$.
The even-numbered partial sums converge, in fact they are all equal to $0$.
But the series does not converge.